# How can I only display one link rather than many?

Tags: categories

So using this snippet:

```
   <?php
   foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
if (cat_is_ancestor_of(10, $childcat)) {
echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($childcat->cat_ID).'">';
 echo $childcat->cat_name . '</a>';
}}
?>
```

I'm able to output all the child categories of the parent category with the id 106. However, I only want to output *one* child category if there's more than one. How can I do this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `break` statement to abort after the first cat that is found and that is a child category.

```
foreach ( get_the_category() as $cat )
{
    if ( cat_is_ancestor_of( 10, $cat ) )
    {
        printf(
            '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
            get_category_link( $cat->cat_ID),
            echo $cat->cat_name
        );
        break;
    }
}
```